# Most optimal method to check length of a parquet table in dbfs with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, parquet

I have a table on dbfs I can read with pyspark, but I only need to know the length of it (nrows). I know I could just read the file and do a `table.count()` to get it, but that would take some time.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Parquet files store row counts per rowgroup, and as a separate tally in file footers. Spark is able to "cheat" by getting counts from there instead of scanning the whole file, making `count()` operation quite efficient (unless you have millions of files of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid not.

Since you are using dbfs, I suppose you are using Delta format with Databricks. So, theoretically, you could check the metastore, but:

> The metastore is not the source of truth about the latest information
> of a Delta table

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#control-data-location